# How to create different product page layout based on different phtml file in magento2 Product page

Tags: magento2

I want to display different `phtml` file on simple product based on page layout while choosing from -`(catalog-Product-design section)` .

Can any one help me with this on how to achieve this.  thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to create different layout product wise , you can use below guide for that

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/product-layouts.html